# Angular 4 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Bittrex

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs, bitcoin

Im trying to get some data with Bittrex API in my Angular 4 app but it is not working. I keep getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-ltc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
>   core.es5.js:1085 ERROR 
>   Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}
>   headers
>   :
>   Headers
>   ok
>   :
>   false
>   status
>   :
>   0
>   statusText
>   :
>   ""
>   type
>   :
>   3
>   url
>   :
>   null
>   _body
>   :
>   ProgressEvent
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Body

This is my code:

module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BittrexService } from '../bittrex/bittrex.service'
import { ComprarmonedasComponent } from './comprarmonedas.component';
import { ComprarmonedasRoutingModule } from './comprarmonedas-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, ComprarmonedasRoutingModule, HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [ComprarmonedasComponent],
  providers: [BittrexService]
})
export class ComprarmonedasModule { }
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { BittrexService } from '../bittrex/bittrex.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comprarmonedas',
  templateUrl: './comprarmonedas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comprarmonedas.component.scss']
})
export class ComprarmonedasComponent implements OnInit { 

  constructor(private bittrexService: BittrexService) {
  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.bittrexService.getPrices()
  .subscribe(
    (data: Response) => console.log(data)
  );
}
 }
```

bittrex.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";



@Injectable()
export class BittrexService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getPrices() {
    return this.http.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-ltc');
  }

}
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: ***Plus One*** because this is actually a programming question related to Bitcoin.